# The saved information in the .json file of the torch profiler

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, profiler

I have profiled my model using the torch profiler:

```
from torch.profiler import profile, record_function, ProfilerActivity
import torch
with profile(activities=[
    ProfilerActivity.CPU, ProfilerActivity.CUDA], record_shapes=True) as prof:
    with record_function("model_inference"):
        model(input)
profiling_results.export_chrome_trace("resnet18_trace_cuda.json")
```

I am not familiar with the terms that are saved in the .json file.
I appreciate it if I know each of the terms:

```
 "traceEvents": [
  {
    "ph": "X", "cat": "cpu_op", 
    "name": "aten::zeros", "pid": 867040, "tid": 867040,
    "ts": 1668551166936236, "dur": 23,
    "args": {
      "Trace name": "PyTorch Profiler", "Trace iteration": 0,
      "External id": 376,
      "Input Dims": [[], [], [], [], []], "Input type": ["", "Scalar", "", "", "Scalar"]
    }
  },...
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can open the json with chrome. Maybe this will help you to understand the data.

From the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.profiler.profile.export_chrome_trace.html):

> The checkpoint can be later loaded and inspected under chrome://tracing URL.